# filter packet data based on the type of content they carry

Tags: android, tcpdump, packet-capture, tizen

I want to `filter` the packet data based on the type of data they carry. I mean is it `possible to recognize` whether the packet carries **text/audio/video/other** type of information by analyzing the packet header or the payload?

Also, I want to be able to do this in `real time;` so that I can keep track of How much of data has been used up in `text/audio/video` etc.. Can these things be done using tcpdump? I want to run in a `tizen/android` phone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things might be needed to achieve this.

In Tizen, you need su access to the device and install tcpdump and a host of other libraries like libpcap for example. 
For HTTP you could rely on MIME headers. 
You could use pre-defined standard ports in certain cases.
For Audio and Video you could examine the payload and see if the header matches and then classify.

But to generalize it across all data formats is going to take some work beyond simply reusing existing tools like tcpdump.

Comment: I made use of tcpdump to take the log and then tried to classify them (not all.. but some) based on the MIME data types... Then I tried to catch the url + application and classify the data.. I also classified further based on the standard port range [eg VoIP in skype]. Some classification was done by examining the packet size [ eg. audio packets have small size etc.]. But you are right, all these methods didn't give me accurate results and one cannot proceed simply using tcpdump. Also real-time service was not achieved using the methods...